# How to specify resourses path in a Java library?

Tags: java, spring, jar, thymeleaf

I prepared a Java library that makes downloadable PDF and HTML from a specific json file.
The library contains a controller which can be called to get access to the page with links to download HTML and PDF files. I wanted to use the controller with Thymeleaf.

The only problem is that when I add the library to projects the library cannot access resouses inside the jar file  - *.jpeg file which I use in PDF, and *.html which I wanted to use with the controller.

Files themselves are in *.jar file of the library, but when I run the project I get an IO exception when the app tries to read the image. I tried different ways of writing file path, but even if I hardcode an absolute path of the image in the library it doesn't work.

```
onOpenDocumentjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nikiforov-java/.m2/repository/ru/companyname/libname/LibName/1.0-SNAPSHOT/LibraryName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/img/image.jpeg
```

An Image class is from OpenPdf library - `import com.lowagie.text.Image;`
This is how I try to read a jpeg file:

```
public Image image;
image = Image.getInstance("/home/nikiforov-java/.m2/repository/ru/companyname/libname/LibName/1.0-SNAPSHOT/LibraryName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/img/image.jpeg");
```

Before extracting to a library the code was in the main project and there was no problem with resources. The issue appeared when I extracted this functionality into a library.

In case of HTML template (documentation.html) I got an exception as well:
[o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Failed to complete request: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'documentation' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'.

I tried to change Thymeleaf resources using `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`, but it didn't help.

Temporarily I just don't use *.jpeg file and return hardcoded HTML String from my controller.

Please help me to figure out what I do wrong. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you load the files? Please show the relevant code

Comment: @dunni, This is how I try to read a jpeg file: `public Image image;
Image = Image.getInstance("/home/nikiforov-java/.m2/repository/ru/companyname/libname/LibName/1.0-SNAPSHOT/LibraryName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/img/image.jpeg");` An Image class is from OpenPdf library - `import com.lowagie.text.Image;`
Of course, I don't want to use the absolute path of the file.   Before extracting to a library the code was in the main project and there was no problem with resources. The issue appeared when I extracted this functionality into a library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in this way:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
....
public class PageNumbersWatermark extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    public Image headerImage;
...
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/img/logo.gif");
        headerImage = Image.getInstance(resourceUrl);
....
    }
}
```

public URL getResource(String name) in public final class Class finds a resource with a given name.

In this code snipped OpenPdf library is used.

The *.gif file was located in the resources directory (projectname/src/main/resources/img/logo.gif).